# secure tcp socket and trust

Tags: android, ios, ssl, tcp

If I crate my on own Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol for my app , is this acceptable from app store like google or apple ?
I mean if my application encrypt all payloads with my own secure protocol will google or apple accept my app ?

Comment: Read [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html). Why can't you use TLS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this docs, they could help you understand more about publishing secure and trusted apps to app stores.

[Google Play guidelines](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none)

[Apple App Store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

Comment: I can't see anything about ssl or secure connection , I ask this question because google blocked my app because my app transfer all data over raw tcp connection with nodejs (NOT even HTTP)

Comment: I think you should use TLS if Google blocked your app because it used raw tcp

Comment: It is one of the best-known practices for app developers